# How can you upload directory using node.js?

Tags: node.js, upload, directory

I'm new to node and want to upload directory using node.js. Can anybody please help? Thank You
If it's possible how? and if not then why?

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. What have you tried?

Comment: I do not want to be harsh, but you should have read http://stackoverflow.com/faq before. Make it real specific question and tell us what you have tried and you will probably get an answer.

Comment: I am also searching for the same issue?

Comment: can I add here What i have tried? or do I need to ask an another question?

Answer (score 0):

you can upload only files.
however there are workarounds,you can

1. covert the folder to a zip file (client side), it really depends here on your case.
2. upload the zip file
3. then unzip it in the server

you can use google to find out how to do every step of those.

Answer (score -1):

You can use use any Folder uploading library like https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload or  https://dropzonejs.com which allows you to Drag and Drop whole directory using HTML5 features.

Comment: Here is the full source code for Directory upload in NodeJS
(http://cl.ly/0W2N432v0C18)

Comment: I have tried this but not working. Anybody help me to upload a folder using node.js