# Make Driectory structure like google drive

Tags: node.js, database, npm, directory, upload

Please help with with the database design for the directory table. I want to give option to users to create folder or subfolder and place their files in them or so on. I have seen the Microsoft installer directory table. But I think it will make complexities when I want to get data or structure with respect to usernames.

Comment: Duplicate. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342383/how-can-you-upload-directory-using-node-js

Comment: change of scenerio

Comment: can you provide more information. Thus I might be able to provide an answer to you.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB structure:

```
{
    "user": "Peter",
    "drive": {
          "folders": {
                 "MyExampleFolder": {
                        "files": [ FileUUID, FileUUID ]
                         "folders": [ FolderUUID ]
                  }
           },
           "files": { ... },
     }
}
```

You'll store the folders and files inside "drive", then all the folders go inside "folder" (where inside that you have all the same "files" and "folders" (and so on).

Comment: and how will we implement with mysql??

Comment: I recommend you using MongoDB as it doesn't needs to have a defined structure. Instead SQL databases have defined structures and that can be difficult for you. (Personal Opinion)