# I can't upload nested folders to my server

Tags: node.js, file, directory, multer

I'm trying to upload folders to my nodejs server from my react app, like in google drive. It is important to clarify that I don't want folders to be able to be created in the app and then upload files, I need the folders to be able to be uploaded directly and not lose their structure. I already tried the fs-extra and formidable libraries and they haven't worked for me, do you know any way to upload folders? The same if you know any way with the libraries that I mentioned works, it can even be in another environment that is not nodejs, but not to services like aws, I want to be able to manage everything on my own server. Thanks.

I tried this code and similar to receive the folders, but the videos always go to the same folder even though I have sent them in nested folders, I have not tried to send the folders in zip, but not how useful it is, because I need the videos that are in the folders constantly

```
const express = require('express'); 
const multer = require('multer'); 
const path = require('path'); 
 
const app = express(); 
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' }); 
 
app.post('/upload-folder', upload.array('folders', 12), (req, res) => { 
  req.files.forEach(file => { 
    const dest = path.join('server/folder', file.originalname); 
    fs.rename(file.path, dest, err => { 
      if (err) throw err; 
    }); 
  }); 
  res.send('Carpetas subidas con éxito'); 
}); 
 
app.listen(3000, () => { 
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try zip solution as suggested here [How can you upload directory using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342383/how-can-you-upload-directory-using-node-js)
but if you are open to some third-party file-storage management i think [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/)
would be a good choice.